# How can I allow an admin user to manage product entries after removing file_manager.php from an installation of oscommerce?

Tags: php, e-commerce, oscommerce

I'm very new to OSC and am wondering if anyone else has encountered the same problem I have. I've agreed to help a friend with his installation of OSC with which he's had tons of security problems with. I was able to stop script incursions into his server via the file_manager.php file by eliminating it and removing the necessary line of code from admin/includes/boxes/tools.php.

However, now he would like to be able to upload photos and add new items to his store. I know that it is not best practice, but as he can't pay for services and needs a quick solution, I suggested uploading the file_manager.php file again and re-adding the necessary line of code to admin/includes/boxes/tools.php. However, after doing this, he still can't upload images. The error given is a rather unhelpful "No files were uploaded" message.

I wondered if it isn't a permissions issue with the file_manager.php file, but after (temporarily) giving the file a 777 permission and seeing that it still doesn't work, I'm at a loss.

Any ideas? And thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is best to remove the file_manager.php and all associated code from your site.  It has a known vulnerability than can leave your site open to hack attempts if it is not secured.
Do a search on Google for 'file_manager.php vulnerability oscommerce' and learn more about this.

You also do not use the file_manager to upload products.  Under the catalog menu in the admin section you will find the area where you create categories and can add new products to the catagories.